# How to hide table data with condition?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the below table:

```js
$(function () {
    $("#table-application-case-columns").columns({
        data: application_case,
        showRows: [25, 50, 75, 100],
        size: 50,
        schema: [
            {
                header: "　",
                key: "detail",
                template:
                    '<button type="submit" name="select_case_id" value="{{id}}" formaction="Applicant/application_case_update" class="btn btn-success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-level-up" style="color: #fff;"></span>Detail</button>',
            },
            { header: "ID", key: "id" },
            { header: "Application date", key: "application_date" },
            { header: "Application store", key: "application_store" },
            { header: "Status", key: "status", template: '<span class="status-declined">{{status}}</span>' },
            { header: "Interview date", key: "interview_date" },
        ],
        pageHandler: function () {
            this.create();
            checkDeclinedStatus();
        },
    });

    checkDeclinedStatus();

    // Greyout if status is "Quit"
    function checkDeclinedStatus() {
        $(".status-declined").each(function () {
            var status = $(this).text().trim();
            var row = $(this).parent().parent();
            if (status == "Quit") {
                row.css("background-color", "#b1b2b4");
                row.css("color", "#5c5959");
                row.find("td").css("border-bottom", "1px solid #c3c0c0ad");
                row.find("td").css("border-right", "1px solid #a4a4a5");
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Now I need to hide rows having status = "quit" instead of changing their background color.
I tried replacing the CSS setting by something like `row.hide = "true"` but it doesn't work.
Hope anyone can help me with this lib. (https://michaeleisenbraun.com/columns/)

P/s: I'd rather set by JS than change SQL condition because the compare value ("quit") is changeable. Thank you.

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example of this code or perhaps a JS fiddle demo would be perfect. Thanks

Comment: Why is this tagged with `json`?

Comment: No idea what `row` is or even `this` giving `$(this).parent().parent()` - but, *assuming* the variable named "row" is a "row" as in `<tr>` then `row.hide()` would hide the "row"

Comment: As you're using a 3rd party library to manage your table, with `showRows: [25, 50, 75, 100]` giving page sizes, note that if you manually hide rows on the *rendered* table (rather than via the library) then your page size will be wrong - eg show 25 rows, but hide 20 of them will not give a page size of 25

Comment: @Andreas I have no idea of this. Just because the table is created with json data so I added this.  Now going to delete. Sorry

Comment: @freedomn-m  I haven't thought of `showRows: [25, 50, 75, 100]` before, maybe page size would be wrong as you said. But even so I still want to try.
I'm not one writing this code but as I know `$(this)` is the `$(".status-declined")` value in the foreach loop, then `$(this).parent()` shows its cell and `$(this).parent().parent()` is the total row...

Comment: So just `row.hide()` then

Comment: @freedomn-m `row.hide()` as well as `row.css('display', 'none')` ... do not work...

Comment: Then you'll have to provide the *rendered* html - or a snippet that includes columns.js and generates the HTML

Comment: @freedomn-m hmm I tried with jsfiddle but my problem is that I dont know how to add the library well. I'll back when having finished it. thank you very much.

Comment: Had a quick look, but there doesn't appear to be a CDN for columns.js, so you'll have to include it in the js box, SO doesn't like linking to the raw file in github